# I have purchase orders, SKUs and Sizes for each SKU, I want to identify purchase orders with only one size type

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have thousands of Purchasing Orders.

Some Purchase orders come with 1 Product (SKU), some come with 2 Products, some with 3 products and so on... (Some with 20 products).

Every product or SKU has assigned a weight classification, let's say Small, Normal 1, Normal 2, Normal 3; Big and Super Big.

I want to identify all the Purchasing Orders that have only one Weight classification.

So:

- If the purchasing Order has 3 products and they are all classified as Small its okey.
- If the purchasing Order has 10 products and they are all classified as Super Big, its okey.
- If the purchasing Order has 15 products and 14 are small and only one of the products is Normal 1 than it is NOT okey.

In picture, greens are okey, red is not okey. How can I identify the Purchasing Orders that are not okey,

[image]

Comment: What's the expected result? 2 columns: 1st column unique orders, 2nd column "OK/Not OK"? Or the weight and "Not OK"?

Comment: The expected result would be a column with "OK/NOT OK".

All the Okeys would mean that all the products of the Purchase Order have the same size.

All the Not Okeys would mean that the products in the purhcasing orther have one or more sizes that are not the same.

Comment: So you mean a column of the size of your data? 5 `OKs` followed by 2 `Nots` for the data in the screenshot?

Comment: In the example of the screen shot it would be as you say, 5 ok and 2 nots.

Comment: Try: `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2,$C$2:$C$8,C2)=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using <kbd>COUNTIFS()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2,$C$2:$C$8,C2)=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2),"OK","NOT OK")
```

---

And Fill Down!!

---

Or, can do some custom formatting like as below:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=N(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2,$C$2:$C$8,C2)=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2))
```

---

And Format the cells as `[Color10][=1]  "✔️ OK";[Red][=0]  "❌ NOT OK"`

---